# Using Merge to create nodes to Neo4J database

Tags: java, neo4j

I am new to Neo4J Cypher database, and I have get a weird "error" while trying to write values using **Merge** into the database.

```
   GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( dbpath);
   ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine( graphDb );;
   try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()){    
        result = engine.execute( youtubeQuery );
        tx.success();
        tx.close();
   }
```

The code runs quietly, and when I refresh the neo4j browser, there are no records. I checked the query works by typing to the Neo4J browser. My dbpath works for reading values from the Neo4J database.

dbpath: localhost:7474/db/data/cypher
explorer: localhost:7474/explorer

What seems to be the problem here? Is it only the path problem or did I miss something before tx.success? Any suggestions?

Comment: The most likely scenario is that the dbpath you're using in the code isn't the same as the dbpath that the browser is pointing at.  It would probably be a good idea to post your server config so we know where that DB is, and let us know what dbpath is in this code.  If they're not the same, there you go.

Comment: http://localhost:7474/db/data/cypher is my dbpath and http://localhost:7474/browser/ is the browser .... the dbpath worked when I tried to read data.

Comment: That is a URL, not a dbpath.  If that's what you're using in your java code, you might want to check your local filesystem; you can't use the RESTful API like that, it might actually be creating a local directory named "localhost..." or something.   I don't mean the URL, I mean check this:   http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-configuration.html#_important_server_configurations_parameters

Comment: What is your server's org.neo4j.server.database.location?   That's what your dbpath should be in the java code.  Also, for this to work, the server can't be running at the same time as the java code, otherwise the db will be locked.

Comment: Thanks!!! I check into conf/neo4j-server.properties file, and add this line - org.neo4j.server.database.location=data/graph.db. And use that as the dbpath, but same results. And so Neo4J must be aborted to update the db? In my merge statement, the update reads the content, so how can that be done if the db is locked?

Comment: Don't add that line -- check the setting that will already be there, and figure out where the database is stored.   Yes, you must stop the server `neo4j stop` (not abort) in order to run your java code successfully.  Only one process can modify your DB at a time.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits There is nothing defined by org.neo4j.server.database.location in the file before. What shall I do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63201/discussion-between-unknown-and-frobberofbits).

Comment: Is there any way I could stop neo4j from the java code. Any commands?